# Functions satisfying the conditions.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = 2x; x \in \mathbb{R}$.
I am asked to find two functions g and h such that they satisfy the two equations
$g \circ f=2gh$,
$f \circ g=h^2-g^2$.

Now, the thing is I am just going crazy to find such functions but it seems impossible for me to find.
I would like to have some hints and ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may assume that both $g$ and $h$ are constants, $g(x)=a, h(x)=b$. So we have

$$
a=2ab \\
2a=b^2-a^2
$$

Solving turns out that $g(x) = h(x) = 0$ work. Simple, but works!

Comment: That means the functions g and h should be null function? Is it absolutely okey to take them as 0?

Comment: Yes! Functions can be whatever you want them to be. Usually. $0$ is not the only solution that the system gives, but why get square roots when the null function satisfies your conditions? If you eventually take some classes on differential equations, you'll remember that you can assume that a function is merely a constant! There might be *other* solutions. But there you have one.